# Проблемы не найдены хотя 100% в коде есть ошибки. visual studio 2022, win 10, 64x

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

В коде 100 % есть ошибки, но ide все равно считает, что их нету. Она просто перестаёт подсвечивать код, но при этом во время компиляции ругается на ошибки.

Перешёл на visual studio 2019. Проблема больше не появляется/редко.

Comment: Сколько в Вашем проекте файлов? Быть может, все ошибки касаются тех файлов, которые Вы ранее не изучали на предмет ошибок? Или же все ошибки появляются в том файле, в котором "проблемы не найдены"?

Comment: Есть ли такие ошибки, которые принадлежат открытому Ваму файлу, который, в свою очередь, отображает "Проблемы не найдены"?

Comment: либо `#pragma once`, либо [Include guard](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)

Comment: Ох, что-то не то и не туда вы засунули при делении на h и cpp...

Comment: Давайте Вы сделаете новый вопрос, указав все необходимые детали вроде кода и т.п., а то обсуждать в комментариях другой задачи как-то не оч